# BCS gap parameter and expansion of trace log term

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, many-body

I have a naive question on the solution to the Gap equation and expansion of trace log term of the effective action of BCS Hamiltonian.

Solving the gap equation, one finds a famous plot of the Gap parameter [image]

One can see that the Gap parameter $\Delta$ is smaller than 1 as long as the temperature is smaller than the critical temperature.

On the other hand, when one integrate out the fermioninc degree of freedom from the BCS Hamiltonian after Hubbard Stranovoich transformation, one finds the effective action

$$
S_{\text{eff}} = \int d \tau d^3 r \text{Tr}\log H_{\text{BdG}} - \frac{1}{g}|\Delta|^2 ,
$$
where $ H_{\text{BdG}} $ is a BdG Hamiltonian where
$$
 H_{\text{BdG}}  = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{\tau}- \epsilon_{\vec{r}}&\Delta\\
\Delta^*&\partial_{\tau}+ \epsilon_{\vec{r}}
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The next step is to expand the trace log term with respect to the Gap parameter $\Delta$ near the critical temperature. This will leads to the Ginzburg-Landau model.

This expansion is justified by the above picture, where the Gap parameter $\Delta$ is smaller than $1$. Therefore the expansion of the trace log does not diverge (i.e. higher order expansion does not increase). In fact, the Gap parameter is smaller than $1$ for all temperatures below the critical temperature $T_c$. Therefore the Ginzburg Landau model applies to temperatures between $(0,T_c)$ .

**My question**: If you have a picture like the below, Could you say that the region indicated in the picture is where the Ginzburg Landau model is a reliable (meaning trace log expansion holds) effective theory?

Sorry for the long question...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always expand the trace-log in powers of $\Delta$. However, if you only want to keep quadratic and quartic terms, you have to be able to argue that $\Delta$ is small. Indeed, this is only true near $T_c$.